# How to write word as dword/qword?

Tags: assembly, x86

I need to take a word and put it in an offset as dword. How do I do it in 86x assembly?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a sign extending load, such as `MOVZX` or `MOVSX` (for zero-extension, used for unsigned or signed extension respectively), then you can use it as a 32bit displacement, eg:

```
MOVSX EAX,AX ;extend 16 bit to 32 bit
MOV EAX,[ESI+EAX] ;load a value using the 32bit displacement
```

(the above example is quite contrived, as there are other instructions for in-register extensions, like `CWD` or `CDQ`, see [this](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.22/as/i386_002dMnemonics.html)).